# Change encoding window console from python

Tags: python, encoding, console

I have some trouble with encoding. I have a program that runs a command in windows console and get the results. In this case it returns some lines from a text file which have accent(tilde in spanish). These accents are not properply encoded.

```
import os
p= os.popen(' chcp 65001 && findstr /s /i  /r /c:"EVNT" '+path+'"\\*-LOG')
tmp = p.read()
```

I have tried the same command directly in console so it's work fine. I can get the words with accent.

```
chcp 65001 && findstr /s /i  /r /c:"EVNT" *-LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an encoding issue. You may want to try

```
p.encode('Unicode')
```

or

```
p.encode('UTF-8')
```

and see if you still cannot display tildes.